# Italic maths in italic text, inconsistent spacing?

Tags: spacing, kerning

Consider the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\begin{document}
    \Huge
    \textit{I I $I$ I I} %\showlists
    
\end{document}
```

It produces five italic uppercase I characters. However, the character set in math mode is spaced inconsistently when compared to the others. Specifically, the `I` is moved a tiny bit to the left. I can not quite figure out why this happens, can anyone explain?

The list output shows an additional `\kern` at the end of math mode. Is this the reason?

```
### horizontal mode entered at line 5
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 I
\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53178 minus 1.02322
\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 I
\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53178 minus 1.02322
\mathon
\OML/cmm/m/it/10 I
\kern0.7847 %<- this one
\mathoff
\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53333 minus 1.0222
\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 I
\glue 3.57774 plus 1.53178 minus 1.02322
\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 I
\kern 1.58055
\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66498 minus 1.11221
spacefactor 999
```

The same thing seemingly also happens when we use lowercase `a`s instead. However, the effect is less pronounced (you need a very keen eye), and there is no (!) `\kern` generated.

Is there a way to ensure consistent spacing here, while still using math mode?

[image: the inconsistently spaced I]

Comment: The extra space in math mode is known as the "italic correction", and it is there to ensure proper placement of sub- and superscripts.  Also, the intention of math mode italic is to visually indicate that individual letters, indicating variables, are multiplying one another, not forming a word.  There are many questions here asking why strings of letters in math mode don't form nice neat words; if an actual italic word is wanted in math mode, it should be marked as `\mathit{...}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for your comment, unfortunately `\mathit` does only increase the space, since it adds an additonal italic correction at the end. So it only makes it worse, and does not solve the problem, which is not surprising since I don't actually have several letters in math mode!

Comment: I'm not able to test this just now, but it's possible that specifying `$\textit{I}$` might give a less spacy result.  (Although it's not really obvious to me the reason for this.)